# the case of a relative pronoun here

Tags: relative-pronouns, who-whom, case

This is from [a news article](https://apnews.com/article/abortion-north-carolina-governor-veto-rally-52f5b182890d44552a3287dee2aaf5b3) :

> Cooper has called out four GOP legislators — three House members and
> one senator — **whom** he said told voters last year that they would
> protect abortion access.

I think the relative pronoun 'whom' should be changed to 'who' here because it is the subject of the verb 'told'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it should be subjective "who" because it is subject of the bracketed embedded "told" clause: "Cooper has called out four GOP legislators — three House members and one senator — whom he said [ ___ told voters last year that they would protect abortion access]". The gap notation '___' indicates the subject position in the embedded clause.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Who" is correct.  How can you tell?  Simplify the statement by removing the descriptive material:  Cooper called out four legislators who told voters....  You wouldn't say "whom" here, so you wouldn't say it in the original, more elaborate sentence, either.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The point is that the pronoun is subject of the embedded "told" clause, and thus should be subjective "who", not accusative "whom"